# How to get automake, libtool, and rpmbuild to work together

Tags: unix, rpm, automake, libtool, rpmbuild

I'm trying to create an RPM of my package, which is built using `automake` and `libtool`, and I've encountered a problem: `rpmbuild` aborts upon discovering that the installed programs of the package contain the pathname of the installation directory for the package's sharable libraries (due to `automake`'s use of the `-rpath` option of `ld`).

I understand that `rpmbuild` does this in order to guarantee that the package is relocatable. My question is what to do about it. I could eliminate the use of sharable libraries (and lose their benefits) or I could tell `automake` to not install the sharable libraries (which would stop it from using the `-rpath` option) and then install them anyway. The cost of this latter option is that it would *require* that the user always have a correctly-set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable -- plus it seems like a bit of a kludge.

Is there another option?

What would you do?

Comment: If you install the libraries as a separate package from the executable, the problem should go away.

Comment: While I don't like it, that is another possible solution. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @William Pursell: I know that's usually the done thing on debian (see e.g., `zeromq-bin`, `libzmq0`, `libzmq-dev` all coming from the one source package). Do you have a link that shows that's best practise for RPM?

Comment: @Jack  I don't have a link--overall I've found documentation for this sort of thing bad and/or obsolete.  I'll try to post a sample spec file later today in exchange for all of the criticism I'm sure it deserves!

Comment: @Jack This looks promising: http://tinymelinux.com/doku.php/build-rpms:splitting (I haven't read it completely, though)

Comment: Could you please clarify this: "rpmbuild aborts upon discovering that the installed programs of the package contain the pathname of the installation directory for the package's sharable libraries (due to automake's use of the -rpath option of ld)."? I've been adding RPATHs to my dynamic executables at build time, and rpmbuild has never complained about it.

Comment: @jayhendren The package contains a library and a program that links against the library. After installation, the installed program contains a reference to the installed, shareable library. My `rpmbuild` refuses to create an RPM file when that is the case.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson could you provide more detail? I understood the first time around, but I don't see why RPM would care one whit about your RPATH or RUNPATH. That is really bizarre. I am able to link an executable against whatever I want, no problem, and put it into an rpm.

Comment: @jayhendren Unfortunately, I switched from GNU's autotools to CMake for creating the binary distribution before I solved this problem and CMake doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The details of this depend on the particular package's build system and which libtool version it is using.

Here are the relevant packaging guidelines from Fedora: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingGuidelines#Beware_of_Rpath

Here is the analogous page from Debian: http://wiki.debian.org/RpathIssue

Wikipedia also has some relevant links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath_(linking)

So you will need to try a few of the suggested techniques for getting rid of the rpath, but which one will work depends on the specifics of your package.